# Worksheet_change shows date as FALSE

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

This is my workbook, so I have a code, I'm using a scanner to scan barcodes. When I scan a barcode it adds "1" to the qty(Column c), I also want to record the date in column F, almost everything works fine except it does not type the date, it types "FALSE". I tried with macro+if formula (if cellrange=1,=(now),""). This works but unfortunately I use the workbook in Shared Mode and you cannot use macros in Shared Mode and vba is my last solution.

I am a beginner in VBA.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Item As String
Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim rFound As Range

'Don't run the macro if:
'Target is not a single cell:
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
'or Target belongs to the A1.CurrentRegion:
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1").CurrentRegion) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Avoid the endless loop:
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Looks for matches from the here first:
Set SearchRange = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)

Item = Target.Value

'Clears the Target:
Target.Value = ""

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SearchRange, Item) > 0 Then
'There's a match already:
    Set rFound = Columns(1).Find(What:=Item, After:=Cells(1, 1) _
            , LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
            , SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
'Adds one to the Quantity:
        rFound.Offset(0, 2).Value = rFound.Offset(0, 2).Value + 1
        rFound.Offset(0, 5).Value = rFound.Offset(0, 5).Value2 = Now



Else

'Writes the value for the Barcode-list:
Range("A" & SearchRange.Rows.Count + 1).Value = Item

'Looks for the match from sheet "Inventory" column A
    With Sheets("Inventory")
        Set rFound = .Columns(1).Find(What:=Item, After:=.Cells(1, 1) _
                , LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
                , SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        On Error GoTo 0

            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
'Writes the Product Name and puts 1 to the Quantity column:
                Range("B" & SearchRange.Rows.Count + 1).Value = rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Range("C" & SearchRange.Rows.Count + 1).Value = 1


            End If
    End With
End If

'Enable the Events again:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Le:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("C:C"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 3
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `rFound.Offset(0, 5).Value = rFound.Offset(0, 5).Value2 = Now` returns `False` in all circumstances... "Value2 property doesn't use the Currency and Date data types." and `Now` cannot be the same with something previously recorded...

Comment: "i use the workbook in Shared Mode and you cannot use macros in Shared Mode and vba is my last solution" - yet, in Excel, VBA are considered macros...

Comment: Try changing of `rFound.Offset(0, 5).Value = rFound.Offset(0, 5).Value2 = Now` with `rFound.Offset(0, 5).Value = Now`.

Comment: @brax prolly didnt express myself corectly, this is my macro Function LastModified(c As Range)
LastModified = Date
End Function
and formula:IF([@qty]>0, lastmodified([@qty]), "") does not work properly in Shared Mode..@FaneDuru tried that before, it does not work

Comment: I did try also with another code to capture Date but it seems the code works only if the cell is modified by user(manually type data in column c) and not by VBA, edited the first the post and posted the code. I need to find a way the second code(that shows the date) to be triggered from first code, ps i know you cant run two worksheet_change events in the same time so i will use another sub to call both codes

Comment: Sorry.  Yes, scanner simulates Enter automatically, i think i tried with SendKeys and it didnt work but i may did it incorectly

Comment: @user12513810: Can you post here the used code?

Comment: Try [this](https://easyupload.io/zoqsvc) please. I added a line `rFound.Offset(0, 5).Value = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")` and commented all un-useful code of `Module1`. Does it work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace this row:

```
rFound.Offset(0, 5).Value = rFound.Offset(0, 5).Value2 = Now
```

with this one:

```
rFound.Offset(0, 5).Value = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Then comment the line of the `Worksheet_change`:

```
codetwo Target
```

and do the same with all rows of `Module` module